# BufferedReader String check

Tags: java, bufferedreader

Could you please recommend the best way how to:

1. check that `input.readLine().isEmpty()`
2. check that  `Integer.parseInt(input.readLine()) <10 && Integer.parseInt(input.readLine()) > 1`

I do not know how to do this using fewer iterations:

```
    System.out.println("Please enter N natural number of Strings :");
    BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    try {

        if (input.readLine().isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println("Dear User! \nYou did not specify number of Strings \nOr number of Strings greater then 10 \nOr number of Strings less then 1");

        } else {
            int numberOfString = Integer.parseInt(input.readLine());
            stringArrayList = new ArrayList<String>(numberOfString);
```

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ this site would be better suited for your needs

Answer (score 3):

You should call `readLine()` *once* and use that input - otherwise you're checking a different line each time!

```
String line = input.readLine();
// readLine returns null for "end of input"
if (line == null || line.isEmpty()) {
    // Report error
} else {
    int number = Integer.parse(line);
    if (number < 1 || number > 10) {
        // Report error 
    } else {
        // Handle success
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using `input.readLine` twice:

- Firstly when you check for empty
- Secondly in your `else` statement, when you parse the `int`

Your first `if` statement is always evaluated (except if you throw `NullPointerException` that is :), but the value is never retrieved.

Therefore, if your first evaluation returns `false`, your `int` parsing will be based on the second line read by your `input`.

Assign `String line = input.readLine()` and reference `line` in both cases.

Also remember to check for `null`!

Answer (score 0):

You are using input.readLine() two times.So take it by storing in the string temp variable.

```
String temp=input.readLine();
if(Integer.parseInt(temp)>10)  //or whatever you want
{
    //put your code here
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are somethings that you need to consider to write safe code
1 - JavaDoc for `BufferedReader.readLine` says

> Returns: A String containing the contents of the line, not including
>   any line-termination characters, or null if the end of the stream has
>   been reached

So its important that you check for that too, but as you are using System.in as input stream, I think there wont be any issue.

Simplest way would be to read the string first:

```
System.out.println("Please enter N natural number of Strings :");
    BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
do {
 String line = input.readLine();
 if(line != null) {
  if(list.trim().equals("")) {
   System.out.println("Dear User! \nYou did not specify number of Strings");
  } else {
   int numberOfString = 0;
   try {
    numberOfString Integer.parseInt(line);
    if(numberOfString < 1 || numberOfString > 10) {
     System.out.println("Dear User! \Number of string is either smaller then 1 or greater than 10");
    } else {
     stringArrayList = new ArrayList<String>(numberOfString);
     //ReadString(input);
     break;
    }        
   } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    System.out.println("Dear User! \n" + line + " is not acceptable number");
   }
  }
 }
} while(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

HUGE thank you!

my code looks :

```
    public void initializeStringArr() {
    System.out.println("Please enter N natural number of Strings :");
    BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    try {
        String line = input.readLine();
        if (line.isEmpty() || line == null) {
            System.out.println("Dear User! \nYou did not specify number of Strings ");
        } else {
            int numberOfString = Integer.parseInt(line);
            if(numberOfString<=1 || numberOfString>10 ){
                System.out.println("Number of Strings greater then 10 \n" + "Or number of Strings less(equals) then 1");
            }  else {
                stringArrayList = new ArrayList<String>(numberOfString);
                for (int i = 0; i < numberOfString; i++) {
                    System.out.println("Please enter your string :");
                    BufferedReader newStr = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
                    stringArrayList.add(newStr.readLine());
                }
            }
```

Comment: reverse this check "if (line.isEmpty() || line == null)"